# Firebase crashlytics not working in flutter android

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics

I am new to firebase crashlytics, I have added crashlytics as referred from [flutter fire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/overview/) and it is working fine for new project but I am getting error for my client app.

I am not sure where to look for since there is no error at all.
Also after adding firebase crashlytics I am not able to generate build release apk as well. But While generating release apk I am getting this error.

Please let me know if you have anything in your mind.
Only thing that I can doubt is that I have change package name but I updated both firebase and android package as well. SO I am confused now.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease' (type 'UploadMappingFileTask').
> File 'C:\flutter\alink\build\app\generated\res\google-services\release\values\values.xml' specified for property 'googleServicesFile' does not exist.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to change your dependencies on android/build.gradle ?

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
}
```

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/6705#issuecomment-899098165 this comment say work for me. And than I tried too. It's work